# Как сервер должен удалять поля в update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Предположим у меня приложение-опросник, poll имеет много questions, они имеют много answers, все соединены друг с другом через `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Клиент взаимодействует с сервером через json-api, заполняет в форме все поля, нажимает на save, данные отправляются на `create`

```
  def create
    @poll = current_user.polls.create(poll_params)

    if @poll.persisted?
      render 'show', status: :created
    else
      render json: { errors: @poll.errors }, status: :internal_server_error
    end
  end

  private
    def poll_params
      params.require(:poll).permit(
        :title,
        # has many
        {
          questions: [
            :id,
            :content,
            {
              # has many
              :options => [:id, :content]
            }
          ]
        }
      )
    end
```

Вопрос в том, что делать, если на странице `edit`, клиент решит удалить некоторые поля? Новые данные при сохранении  отправляются на `update` `(@poll.update_attributes(poll_params)`) и там я должен удалять все вложения poll кроме самого poll и заново их создавать? или в запросе должно быть особое поле `deleted_attr` с типом и id всех удаленных полей?
Данные должны отправляться одним запросом, ведь вдруг клиент при форматировании решит аннулировать удаление поля

## Модели

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  # alias
  def questions=(value)
    value.is_a?(Array) && value.first.is_a?(Hash) ? (self.questions_attributes = value) : super
  end
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  # alias
  def answers=(value)
    value.is_a?(Array) && value.first.is_a?(Hash) ? (self.answers_attributes = value) : super
  end
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  acts_as_voteable # thumbs_up gem
end
```

Comment: *Некоторые поля* -- в смысле, некоторые ассоциированные (вложенные) модели?

Comment: да, к примеру удалить поле вопрос или одно из его полей ответ

Comment: Если не сложно приведите модели, точнее их части, в которых определены ассоциации?

Comment: @cheops Пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации к `accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), **удаление** записей производится путём указания в параметрах ключа `_destroy` с "правдивым" значением (чем угодно кроме `false` или `nil`).

Когда он есть в записи, система при сохранении устроит так, чтобы в базе его больше не было, либо не сохранив его (если его там и не было), либо удалив (если был).